# Изменение центра карты, созданной в конструкторе Яндекс.Карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-embed

Поскольку гугл решил, что деньги важнее пользователей и прикрыл адекватное использование API карт, встал вопрос о переезде на карты Яндекса.

Раньше использовал Fusion Tables, туда выгружаешь таблицу с адресами, геокодируешь, получаешь id карты и далее можно с ней взаимодействовать через js на сайте.

Создал таблицу для ЯКарт, загнал в конструктор, всё хорошо. Добавил на сайт. Но не могу подключиться к карте, чтобы менять её центр (селект по разным городам).

Может кто знает, как решить проблему? Добавление точек по факту загрузки карты мне кажется затратным делом (примерно 1200 точек надо проставить).

Comment: картой Конструктора нельзя управлять программно, в чём проблема с показом карты на js api? точки же всё равно добавляются на карту при загрузке страницы

Comment: @Reni, когда я геокодировал адреса из бд через яндекс геокодер через php - это занимало достаточно много времени. Если через json выгружать на карту точки - это будет быстрее?

Comment: Да, конечно. Геокодирование это сетевые запросы - время уходит на них. Только обратите внимание, что сохранять к себе результаты геокодирования нельзя.